# How to combine multi key and values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry because my english not good. I have contains structure as shown below. I want combine values of "categories" if values of "domain_id" the same.
Thanks so much for your help!
My Json file:

```
[
  {
    "categories": [
      "Potential Misc Exploit",
      "Misc Exploit"
    ],
    "domain_id": 3
  },
  {
    "categories": [
      "Web Exploit"
    ],
    "domain_id": 1
  },
  {
    "categories": [
      "Misc Exploit"
    ],
    "domain_id": 3
  },
  {
    "categories": [
      "Misc Exploit"
    ],
    "domain_id": 3
  },
  {
    "categories": [
      "Misc Exploit"
    ],
    "domain_id": 3
  },
  {
    "categories": [
      "Web Exploit"
    ],
    "domain_id": 3
  },
  {
    "categories": [
      "Access Denied",
      "ACL Deny"
    ],
    "domain_id": 1
  }
]
```

i want output have structure like this.

```
{{"domain_id" : 1. "categories": ["Access Denied", "ACL Deny", "Web Exploit"]}, {"domain_id" : 2, "categories": [....]} {"domain_id" : , "categories": [Misc Exploit,..]}}
```

Comment: What is your expected output and what you have tried so far?

Comment: hi! i'm begining with python. i have no idear for this. i want output have structure like this.
````
{{"domain_id" : 1.
"categories": ["Access Denied",
      "ACL Deny", "Web Exploit"]},
{"domain_id" : 2,
"categories": [....]}
{"domain_id" : ,
"categories": [Misc Exploit,..]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary dictionary to group the items by the domain_id values and then get the values from it to turn the result back into a list of dictionaries.

```
data = [
  {
    "categories": [
      "Potential Misc Exploit",
      "Misc Exploit"
    ],
    "domain_id": 3
  },
  {
    "categories": [
      "Web Exploit"
    ],
    "domain_id": 1
  },
  {
    "categories": [
      "Misc Exploit"
    ],
    "domain_id": 3
  },
  {
    "categories": [
      "Misc Exploit"
    ],
    "domain_id": 3
  },
  {
    "categories": [
      "Misc Exploit"
    ],
    "domain_id": 3
  },
  {
    "categories": [
      "Web Exploit"
    ],
    "domain_id": 3
  },
  {
    "categories": [
      "Access Denied",
      "ACL Deny"
    ],
    "domain_id": 1
  }
]
```

Loop through data and accumulate in result dictionary. Note: I assumed that you would not want duplicates in the categories list so I used a set to keep only the distinct values.

```
result = dict()
for d in data:
    merged = result.setdefault(d["domain_id"],{**d,"categories":set()})
    merged["categories"].update(d["categories"])
result = list(result.values())
```

output:

```
print(result)

[
  {'categories': {'Web Exploit', 'Misc Exploit', 'Potential Misc Exploit'}, 'domain_id': 3},
  {'categories': {'Web Exploit', 'Access Denied', 'ACL Deny'}, 'domain_id': 1}
]
```

Comment: so if i dont want merge dupilcate, how can i do? thanks you

Comment: replace `set()` with `list()` and `.update` with `.extend`